# actionscript - base64decoder of an encoded string is returning an empty xml object

Tags: xml, actionscript, base64, decoder

I am being passed a url that has been base64 encoded via the php urlencode function.  I pick up the url basically as a string in actionscript so I don't need to load an file of any sort. I need to then decode that string into an xml object.  Code is as follows:

```
urlStr = InParameters.md; //this is the incoming encoded url
var Base64:Base64Decoder = new Base64Decoder; 
var myXML:XML = new XML(Base64.decode(urlStr));
trace("My XML", myXML)
```

My xml object is coming up empty, so I am clearly missing something.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to print out the result of Base64.decode(urlStr)? Perhaps the XML is not well-formed?

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out this morning.  It needed to be flushed.   var myXML:XML = new XML(Base64.flush());